# pyspark textfile() is lazy operation in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have read that sc.textFile(), sc.parallelize() etc are lazy operation and are evaluated only when action is called.

```
For example consider code snippet:-
rdd1 = sc.textFile("file:///hello.txt")
rdd1
rdd1.getNumPartitions()
rdd1.count()
```

But in above case if "sc.textFile" is lazy operation and evaluated only when we call rdd.count() function then how come we are able to find number of partition it has created using "rdd.getNumPartitions()" even before "rdd.count()" function is called.
Also partition are loaded in storage memory on textFile() or on action function count()?
Because after sc.textFile(), I could see some storage memory of executor are occupied i.e 32.7 KiB in this case.See image
[image]

Comment: One question - what is the reason for using RDD API instead of the DataFrame counterpart: `spark.read.text(...)` ?

Answer (score 2):

Although `sc.textFile()` is lazy, doesn't mean it does nothing :)

You can see that the signature of `sc.textFile()`:

```
def textFile(path: String, minPartitions: Int = defaultMinPartitions): RDD[String]
```

`textFile(..)` creates a `RDD[String]` out of the provided data, a distributed dataset split into partitions where each partition holds a portion of the data. You can think of it as a mapping between the underlying data and the processing units which will do the actual work.

The laziness referred to the processing itself -- only when an action is triggered, those partitions are processed (transformed, filtered, etc) but the mapping of the underlying data into RDD happens as part of the `textFile(..)` operation.